# Esper stops working after a while running

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio, esper

I'm using Esper 4.9 with Mule 3.4. I have some different patterns to work with stock quotes. They are all working good, at some point, without any reason (I don't really know if I can see a log only from Esper), Esper does not process more events anymore, event though they are being sent to it.

As I have said, I have no log for this, since all I have is Mule log but nothing from Esper. But if any other information is needed, I will be able to provide it.

I'm not using the Mule Esper Connector since I'm not able to make it work.

Has anyone ever get this problem before?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommending reviewing the information in the performance section of the Esper docs. There are common pitfalls that you can walk into designing EPL statements that eat memory or CPU. You could also do some profiling to find that out. A profiler will also tell you if locking is a problem.
For detailed help contact the Esper user mailing list and be prepared to reproduce your problem by providing a test class when posting to the user mailing list. Esper does produce logs, check @Audit and the docs on logging.

Comment: Thanks for the @Audit thing. It seems that the problem is not with Esper but Mule. I'm sending back the events from Esper to Mule and, at some point, this events are not received in Mule anymore although Esper still calculate them. I will try to find out why... any ideas?